# How to direct all sub-captions of the subfigures in a central caption

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats, subcaption

Is there a way to direct all the \caption{}'s found within multiple nested subfigure environments within a central \begin{figure} environment given as

```
\begin{figure} ...
\begin{subfigure}...\caption{}...\end{subfigure}\\
\begin{subfigure}...\caption{}...\end{subfigure}
\caption{}...     <---------------direct all sub-captions here
\end{figure}
```

such that all the subfig captions go in the last caption belonging to the figure (as marked above) where they are labelled appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need a subcaption for every subfigure, e.g. a), b), c), d). Otherwise you'd write things like "the picture second from left" to refer to a subfigure.

So all you have to do is to write a long caption and refer inside this caption to your subfigures.

---

Edit: Answering a comment of the OP, how to refer to a subcaption:

The question does not provide a MWE, so I have no clue about the way you write your captions and subcaptions. Let us assume that you use the packages caption and subcaption, then you probably just could write `\subref{<key>}` and you are done, see the manual of subcaption, 6.1.

Comment: How do you refer the subcaption to the main caption?

Comment: @user2822693 I added some text to my answer, but please change your username to a nic and provide a MWE.